# Comparison Between Variable And Loop Iterator In Template Always Failing

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to print something whenever an `int` variable from one of my models == my `iteration` of the loop.

My `iteration` counter increments correctly, and the test passes if I change it to `if data.number == '1'`.

edit: I should mention that `if data.number == 1` fails, which I think is strange.

I've read a lot of posts about this and I'm sure this should work, but it doesn't.

```
{% for iteration in range %}

{% for data in lesson_data.all %}

# this never passes
{% if data.number == iteration|add:"1" %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `forloop.counter` in your loop? It starts from 1 and end to the for loop iteration.

Comment: I have: ```{% if data.number == forloop.counter %}``` and it also never passes. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I had to cast:

```
{% if data.number|add:0 == iteration|add:"1" %}
```